# method_exchangeImplementations causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I was trying to test how would method_exchangeImplementations behave in different situations. When I tried following code, I got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I don't know why the program ended with this error. Here is the code in my project:

```js
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@interface Person : NSObject
@end

@implementation Person

- (void)say{
    NSLog(@"Person");
}

@end

@interface Student : Person
@end

@implementation Student


- (NSString *)say {
    return nil;
}

@end


@interface Doctor : Person

@end

@implementation Doctor


@end


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Student *stu =[Student new];
    Doctor *dr = [Doctor new];
    Person *person = [Person new];
    Method studentMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([Student class], @selector(say));
    Method doctorMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([Doctor class], @selector(say));


    [stu say];
    [dr say];
    method_exchangeImplementations(studentMethod, doctorMethod);
 
    [stu say];
    [dr say];
    [person say];
}


@end
```

There is one thing I have to mention which is the -say method in Student class. The return value of the say method is NSString *. I don't whether it is allowable to have the overriding method written with a different return type. At least, the compiler didn't stop me from doing that, maybe it still considers it as a normal override.

**Could anyone get me out of this error? Please explain why the compiler allows a override with a different return type as well. Thanks!**

Comment: Just add one thing, the error shows at the line of the second call of stu instance.

Comment: You have changed method's implementations, but haven't changed method's type encoding.

Comment: @Cy-4AH It makes sense. I'll try. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler (and ARC) tends to always retain the returned value of a swizzled method. It often causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the returned values are not NSObjects (becauses it sends the `retain` message to a non-objC instance).

If one of your exchanged methods needs to return a non-objC value (int, C string, etc...or even a void), casting the function pointer at method call lets the compiler know it should not retain it (which avoids the crash). See the second footnote of https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/16/right-way-to-swizzle/ for more info.

I hope this helps, I have lost days (and nights) before finding this unexpected footnote that saved my life!

Comment: Link is down, anyone found its new location if there's one? Thanks